# Is there a DRY way of Flex ordering?

Tags: html, css, sorting, flexbox

Newbie to flex use/web development.

I currently have 6 boxes within a flex container ordered like this for mobile devices:
[Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM5uC.png)

with code more or less like this (CSS not included, but the class “box” is the grey box you see above):

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class=“box item” />
    <div class=“text item”>
        <h4>Text</h4>
    </div>
    <div class=“box item” />
    <div class=“text item”>
        <h4>Text</h4>
    </div>
    <div class=“box item” />
    <div class=“text item”>
        <h4>Text</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I want for mobile devices!

For desktop however, I’d like to achieve this: [Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcIz6.png)

Currently, the only way I’m achieving this is by using this unappealing flex order css:

```
item:nth-of-type(1) {order:1;}
item:nth-of-type(2) {order:2;}
item:nth-of-type(3) {order:4;}
item:nth-of-type(4) {order:3;}
item:nth-of-type(5) {order:5;}
item:nth-of-type(6) {order:6;}
```

My question is, is there a way to achieve my desired goal (i.e. switching the order of items 3 and 4) without having to order every single item in the container creating a yucky, repetitive block of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that with only 2 CSS selectors, and with `order` defaults to `0`, we re-position item 3 and 5/6, here done with a media query for screens wider than 600px, to `1` and `2`.

```
.item:nth-of-type(3)   { order:1; }               /*  put 3 after 4   */
.item:nth-of-type(n+5) { order:2; }               /*  put 5,6 after 3 */
```

Stack snippet

```css
.flex-container { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.item           { height: 50px; flex-basis: 100%; }
.box            { background: lightgray; }

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .item                  { flex-basis: 50%; }
  .item:nth-of-type(3)   { order:1; }               /*  put 3 after 4   */
  .item:nth-of-type(n+5) { order:2; }               /*  put 5,6 after 3 */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="box item"></div>
  <div class="text item">
    <h4>Text</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box item"></div>
  <div class="text item">
    <h4>Text</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box item"></div>
  <div class="text item">
    <h4>Text</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was great! Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know if you reorder items, you need to explicitly order items after the re-ordered items. So you could probably do:

```
item:nth-of-type(3) {order:4;}
item:nth-of-type(4) {order:3;}
item:nth-of-type(5) {order:5;}
item:nth-of-type(6) {order:6;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever want to switch those two, you could wrap them in another flex container and simply switch ordering within.  That way your outer flow won't have to be redefined, and you could set up the container to be reused in other areas where you need to achieve the same thing.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item one">One</div>
  <div class="item two">Two</div>
  <div class="item three">Three</div>
  <div class="switch">
    <div class="item four">Four</div>
    <div class="item five">Five</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item six">Six</div>
  <div class="item seven">Seven</div>
</div>


.item {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  line-height: 39px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #cecece;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.switch {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .switch .item:nth-of-type(1) {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83xvrg2q/)

Comment: Really liked this approach. Thank you.

Comment: haha, I clicked it but unfortunately I have less than 15 reputation!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to TripWire's answer, you need not to set a *different* order number for *every* `<div>` after the 4th one.

```
.item:nth-of-type(3), .item:nth-of-type(4) ~ .item {order:100;}
.item:nth-of-type(4) {order:50;}
```

A pen: https://codepen.io/israfel/pen/eEbWWG